# Bash find directory name

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, variable

I have a script which takes number then moves it to variable **$n**.
Question how we can find directories which are contains this character/number in their name?

Comment: Directories anywhere in the filesystem? Directories in or under a particular starting point? Just one level of directories or under a tree?

Comment: `find . -type d -name "*$n*"`

Comment: @roaima just one level, find in the name of directory given number

Comment: @ДмитроГородовенко add a `-depth 1`. If you want to learn more about the options that `find` offers, `man find` tells you a lot!

Comment: @choroba thanks!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, rather `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` or portably `! -name . -prune`. `-depth 1` where supported (FreeBSD) would work but would not prevent `find` from crawling  the full directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to look at directories just at the one level you can use a shell glob `*$n*`

```
ls ./*"$n"*
```

This won't differentiate files and directories though. So you could use a loop and check the every type

```
for f in *"$n"*
do
    if [ -d "$f" ]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "$f"
    fi
done
```

Or use `find`, but be aware this will interpret any special characters in `$n` as part of the pattern match.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*$n*"
```

In this particular scenario you could also use this variant

```
find ./*"$n"* -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

Comment: `*"$n"*/` should work to only match directories

Comment: (1) `find *"$n"* …` will choke if there is something whose name begins with **`-`** and contains (the value of) `$n`.  I guess `find ./*"$n"* …` would be safer. (2) In the `find *"$n"* …` construct, you’ll want `-maxdepth 0`. (3) Also note that, if there is no match, the `find *"$n"* …` construct will give an error message (or a ***mess**,*, if `nullglob` is set), while the `-name` version will happily exit with no output.